# How to pass all info from multiply table views cells with the info INSERTED to a new view controller?

Tags: swift, uitableview

```
    @objc func addRow(sender: UIButton!) {
        print("add")
        names.insert("New Name", at: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0)], with: .right)

    }


   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
            names.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: UITableView.RowAnimation.automatic)
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
//        if section == 1 {
//            return carArray.count
//        }
        return names.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
         let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: bondeCellId, for: indexPath) as! BondCell
//
//        if let lbl = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(101) as? UILabel {
//            lbl.text = names[indexPath.row]
//        }
//
//        if let btnDelete = cell.contentView.viewWithTag(102) as? UILabel {
//            btnDelete.addTarget(self, action: #selector(deleteRow()), for: .touchUpInside)
//        }

        return cell

    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHZWp.png)I am fairly knew to programing and don’t know a lot.

I have built table view that lets the user add more table cells if they press the add button.
So the user will add more table views on depending if more information is needed.

The problem is to understanding is how to pass all info from multiply table views cells with the info to a new view controller.

If the User has insert 5 or 10 table cells I want those table cells info to be passed into a one new view controller.

The table view cell contains two text fields and two labels and the text field contains UIpickers and depending what they chose it updates in the labels in cell tables.
But I also want sum of all the table views chosen by the user to be added to a chart that I am making to a new view controller.

Would the labels and the text fields need to get new names each time a new table cell is made?

I am stock with ideas

If the User has insert 5 or 10 table cells I want those table cells info to be passed into a one new view controller.

Comment: Where does the *info INSERTED* come from?

Comment: from the BondCell I have a all the code there in the BondCell have two textfields and two labels as well UIPickerView with information

Answer (score 1):

The code you posted is a mess, and not very helpful with your question. It's mostly boilerplate.

You are thinking about this wrong. Cells don't store data. More generally, view objects don't store data. They display data.

You need a model object that stores the data for your table view. It looks like your table view only has one section, so a simple array would work just fine. Create a struct to hold the info you collect from the user. Let's call that struct CellData. Your model would be an array of CellData structs.

As the user creates new cells, you'd collect the new info and add it to your array.

Then when the user selects cells, and invokes the new view controller, you'd pass the whole array, along with the indexes of the selected cells, to the other view controller. (or perhaps just the structs for each selected item.)

Comment: A learning process :) thank you for answering is it possible if  you can show with a quick example? I  am more a visually person.  Best Regards